# O que devo fazer quando duas perguntas são bastante idênticas, mas uma pede mais detalhes que a outra?

Tags: suporte, perguntas, pergunta-específica, perguntas-duplicadas

Um utilizador [fez uma pergunta sobre o `ARIA`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/160358/o-que-%c3%a9-aria-accessible-rich-internet-applications/160371#160371). [Existe uma pergunta bem parecida que foi feita anteriormente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96948/para-que-servem-os-atributos-aria-em-html5).

Contudo o primeiro utilizador quer mais detalhes sobre o uso do ARIA (uma resposta com um exemplo é portanto bem-vinda), enquanto o segundo pede só uma explicação da sua existência.

O que devo fazer? Marcar como duplicada e dar a minha resposta na outra pergunta?

Dar a minha resposta nesta pergunta e não marcar como duplicada, dando uma referencia para a outra pergunta?

Marcar como duplicada e dar a resposta nesta pergunta?

Comment: Parece duplicata mesmo, mas já que você respondeu nessa mais recente, não precisaria responder na outra, pois caso a pergunta seja considerada duplicata pela comunidade, sua resposta será mantida lá.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Falando em termos gerais, se acha que sua resposta cabe na original até seria uma boa responder lá e fechar a nova como duplicata. Mas não digo que isso é obrigatório e vai depender do caso. Se quer responder tudo acho que é a melhor opção.

Se realmente a pergunta pede novas informações que a outra não pede pode ser interessante respondê-la.

Uma possibilidade é tirar a parte já respondida da pergunta nova e colocar um comentário dizendo que está relacionada. Não costumo fazer isso, perde um pouco o contexto. Mas pode ter caso que é uma boa opção.

Outra possibilidade é responder as partes novas e *linkar* na sua resposta a pergunta original informando que parte foi respondida lá e não tem porque repetir aqui.

Não posso falar por todo que é errado, mas particularmente eu acho errado responder em nova pergunta o que já foi respondido antes em outra pergunta, pelo menos nos casos onde se sabe que há uma duplicata parcial.

Eu não acho que essas duas específicas sejam bem duplicatas, de nenhuma forma, no máximo relacionadas e complementares. Há bastante diferença entre elas, só são sobre o mesmo assunto. Acho que fez certo.